# Why is my render deforming some of my scene?

Tags: rendering

[image]

I've tried rendering with 128 and 300 samples with optix and can't seem to get rid of these strange deformations. Rendering in NLM is super splotchy. Does this have something to do with the materials? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the splotches always the same, or did they change with angle or even different rendering attempts?

Comment: Are you using adaptive sampling by chance? Sometimes fireflies can cause the samples to clump and confuse the AI.

Comment: ZargulTheWizard, the splotches changed with sample amounts and render types and didn't really go away with more samples...just changed a bit.
@HISEROD that was it! What a great tip. Thank you!